# My system restarts after sleep/suspend

Tags: 14.04, 13.10, power-management, suspend

I just replaced windows 7 on my old machine (4 years) with Ubuntu 13.10 and the installation seemed smooth. However,

- when I do a wake-up call from suspend/sleep, the laptop restarts
- when I shutdown, it shuts down pretty fast. Despite being happy of this, it concerned me  and I restarted. Turns out that there was an "report error" dialog box just like when it restarted from suspend/sleep.

Any suggestions? Any installation issue? Driver issue?

Comment: I would suggest you to try with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS first. Ubuntu 13.10 has reached its end of life 2 days ago. It is possible to make an upgrade if you wish...

Comment: My laptop still under this issue. Nobody knows how to fix this?

Comment: I cannot test this anymore, I have upgraded to 14.04 version and I do see the issue persist.

Answer (score 1):

I have found answer on another thread, putting it here for reference.

Go to `/etc/defaults/grub`, change value of

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_sleep=nonvs"
```

Then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Solved :)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please post a link to the article you are referencing to avoid plagiarism.